# Celery tasks in Django are always blocking

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have the following setup in my django settings:

```
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = timedelta(minutes=30)
CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

I've included this under my installed apps:

```
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django'
```

My project structure is (django 1.5)

```
proj
|_proj
  __init__.py
  celery.py      
  |_apps
    |_myapp1
      |_models.py
      |_tasks.py
```

This is my `celery.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings.dev')
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
```

In the main `__init__.py`I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

And finally in *myapp1/tasks.py* I define my task:

```
@task()
def retrieve():
  # Do my stuff
```

Now, if I launch a django interactive shell and I launch the `retrieve` task:

```
result = retrieve.delay()
```

it always seems to be a **blocking** call, meaning that the prompt is bloked until the function returns. The `result` status is SUCCESS, the function actually performs the operations BUT it seems **not to be async**. What am I missing?

Comment: it seems like ALWAYS_EAGER causes thishttp://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

Comment: You are running the celery worker?

Comment: @pynovice yes, it's running but I can't see any message arriving. I executed it either with `celery -A proj worker -l info` `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info` or `python manage.py celeryd` the result doesn't change

Comment: @dm03514 it seems you are right, that was it, could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like [CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eag%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Ber) causes this

> if this is True, all tasks will be executed locally by blocking until
>   the task returns. apply_async() and Task.delay() will return an
>   EagerResult instance, which emulates the API and behavior of
>   AsyncResult, except the result is already evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the
>   queue.